# How can I move the camera under the terrain for a reflection?

Tags: java, opengl, camera, lwjgl

I am attempting to render the reflection of some water.

To create the illusion of reflection, I need the camera to be below the water:
[image]
[image]
(Pictures not drawn by me)

Therefore, I need to move the camera under the water before rendering the scene. I need to move the camera downward by the distance from the camera to the water multiplied by two, and then I need to invert the cameras' pitch.

The problem is that I am currently limited to the fixed-function pipeline to do this, meaning that I must use glTranslatef() and glRotatef() calls to do this.

Here's my current implementation:

```
public void createReflectionTexture(){
    EulerCamera c = Main.TerrainDemo.camera; //This is the camera
    float amtDown = -(2f * (c.y() - 300)); //Amount to move the camera down by. 300 is the height of the water.
    float amtPit = (-(c.pitch() * 2));//Pitch to invert the camera by
    glRotatef(-amtPit, 0, 0, 1); //I have tried both negative and positive values here, neither seem to work.
    glTranslatef(0, amtDown, 0);
    bindArrays();
    fbos.bindReflectionFrameBuffer();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Main.TerrainDemo.renderVBOTerrain();
    fbos.unbindCurrentFrameBuffer();
    unBindArrays();
    glTranslatef(0, -amtDown, 0); /This puts things back to their original translation so I can keep on rendering other objects.
    glRotatef(amtPit, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Unfortunately, in my game, the code creates a completely messy image which definitely is obviously not the correct reflection:
[image]

If I crash my plane into the water and then position the cameras' pitch to 0, it does appear to render the correct objects.

The refraction texture renders perfectly fine.

How can I correctly move the camera below the water to create a scene that looks like reflection when viewed from above?

Comment: Based on the contour of the reflection, are you sure you're rotating and inverting the camera relative to the right axis?

Comment: @PandaConda I'm not rotating it around any axis - I'm just moving the camera below the water and inverting the pitch. Sorry if that wasn't clear previously.

Comment: Try `float amtPit = -c.pitch();` and `glRotatef(-amtPit, 1, 0, 0);`. Also are you sure you want to subtract 300 for the translation?

Comment: If you do want to subtract 300, I think you want to do it after multiplying, not before, since currently you're multiplying a negative number by 2 when y < 300.

Comment: @PandaConda 300 is the height of the water.